# Can i use react w/o a server and as a js file?

Tags: html, reactjs

Basically i have a file that generates some data and writes it to a rudimentary html file. I made a simple React app to better parse and display the data but it's useless if i have to run a server every time.  All i really need is a shortcut html page that runs the react all as a standalone. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for a static templating engine in client side.

However, to answer your question, yes, definitely it's possible. But you just need to include the needed dependencies. Also, note that this is **not optimised** for production.

```js
<!-- The root where React App gets rendered. -->
<div id="root"></div>

<!-- React JS and React DOM Libraries. Add Babel for transpiling, as you might use JSX. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<!-- The real React JSX App -->
<script type="text/babel">
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is React!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the generation of static HTML. You do not need React in such a case. Just use pug or another template engine of your choice.